# NSRange in Strings having dialects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unicode, swift

I was working on an app, which takes input in a language called "Tamil". So in order to find the range of any particular charater in the string i have used the below code.

```
var range = originalWord.rangeOfString("\(character)")
println("\(range.location)")
```

So this works fine except for some cases.

there are some characters like this ->  í , ó . // am just saying an example.

So like this combination, in other languages there are several vowel diacritcs are there.

If i have this word "alv`in"

// which is alvin , but i used "v" with a dialect.
 If i print the unicde value of these characters in xcode, i will get each unicode. But for "v`" there will be two unicode values but its  considered as a single character.

So if i check this character in the above mentioned code. i get the folowing result. Which gives errors in my program.

range.location // 2147483647 , its not a single digit.? why.?

But for other characters its just prints the correct Int Value. //  Single digit like "3"

Anybody have any idea of how to get this done.? How can i achieve this if i use characters with dialets

.?

code given below

```
// userInput = "இல்லம்"

var originalWord : NSString = ("இல்லம்")

   var originalArray = Array("இல்லம்")

        var userInputWord = Array(String(userInput))



       // -------------------------------------------

        for character in String(userInput)
        {
            switch character
            {

            case originalArray[0] :

                // here matches first character of the userinput to the original word first character

                // the character exists at the 0th index


                var range = originalWord.rangeOfString("\(character)")


                if range.location == 0
                {
                     // same character in the same index
                    // correctValue increase by one (cow Value)

                    cowValue += 1

                }
                else
                {
                    // same character but in the different index 
                    // Wrong value increase by one (bull Value)

                    bullValue += 1
                }


            case originalArray[1] :

                // here matches first character of the userinput to the original word first character

                // the character exists at the 1th index


                var range = originalWord.rangeOfString("\(character)")

                println("\(range.location)") // here i get he long Int Value instead of single digit


                if range.location == 1
                {
                    // same character in the same index
                    // correctValue increase by one (cow Value)

                    cowValue += 1

                }
                else
                {
                    // same character but in the different index
                    // Wrong value increase by one (bull Value)

                    bullValue += 1
                }
```

Comment: 2147483647 is actually MAX_INT -- the value assigned to a uint instead of -1. That is to say, `originalWord.rangeOfString` is returning "not found".

Comment: @IanMacDonald If you say like that, So how can i find the  range.location of a character which is a letter with dialect .? (having two unicode values for single character)

Comment: Are you sure that the character you're looking for is specified in the way you have provided? What result do you get when you output the characters individually in a loop using `characterAtIndex:`
?

Comment: @IanMacDonald i was talking about these type of letters -> Ă ă ǖ ᶀ ᶁ ᶂ ᶃ ᶄ ᶆ ᶇ ᶈ ᶉ ᶊ ᶋ ᶌ ᶍ ᶎ ᶏ ᶐ ᶑ ᶒ ᶓ ᶔ ᶕ ᶖ ᶗ ᶘ ᶙ ᶚ.

Comment: A small self-contained code example would be helpful. (Something that we can simply copy/paste into Xcode to reproduce and investigate the problem).

Comment: @IanMacDonald In other languages there will be more than this. I get the exact letter word as output when i print it on xcode and on iPhone. But when i print the word there will be two unicodes for each letter. May be thats the reason for the rangeOfString("") error

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question, please give me your feedback.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I updated the question please give me your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Swift strings instead of `NSString`, because Swift strings have
full Unicode support including composed character sequences, (extended) grapheme clusters etc.

For Swift strings, `rangeOfString()` returns an optional `Range<String.Index>`
which is a bit more complicated to handle. You can also use `find()` instead to
find the position of a character. This might help as a starting point:

```
var cowValue = 0
var bullValue = 0

let userInput = "இல்லம்"
let originalWord = "இல்லம்"
let originalArray = Array("இல்லம்")

for character in userInput {
    switch character {
    case originalArray[0] :
        if let pos = find(originalWord, character) {
            // Character found in string
            println(pos)
            if pos == originalWord.startIndex {
                // At position 0
                cowValue += 1
            } else {
                // At a different position
                bullValue += 1
            }
        } else {
            // Character not found in string
        }

    case originalArray[1] :
        if let pos = find(originalWord, character) {
            // Character found in string
            println(pos)
            if pos == advance(originalWord.startIndex, 1) {
                // At position 1
                cowValue += 1
            } else {
                // At a different position
                bullValue += 1
            }
        } else {
            // Character not found in string
        }
    default:
        println("What ?")
    }
}
```

Comment: -> there is no function called rangeOfString(). Instead thers is one like this -> rangeOfString(string, options, range, locale) .???

Comment: @AppleKid: The options, range and local parameter are *optional*. The above code compiles in Xcode 6.0.1, I checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for NSString's rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex: and rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:

You want to look for Composed Character Sequences, not individual characters.