# Swift IOS: Highlight specific character in Text

Tags: range, uilabel, highlight, title, nsattributedstring

I working with highlighting of particular character in a given text.

Here is my worked code,

```
let titleLabel: UILabel!
let myText = "கொக்கு"
let textToHighlight = "க்"
titleLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
let textStroke: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .strokeColor : UIColor.white,
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
    .strokeWidth : -2.0,
    ]
let textTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myText)
let textHighlightRange = (myText as NSString).range(of: textToHighlight)
textTitle.addAttributes(textStroke, range: textHighlightRange)
titleLabel.attributedText = textTitle
```

The other Texts which i worked and getting the expected results, but only few words specific in tamil languages am facing issues,

Other Languages Text working fine were,

```
let myText = "MyText"
let textToHighlight = "T"

let myText = "मानक हिन्दी"
let textToHighlight = "न"
```

Facing Issues with the text,

> ```
> let myText = "கொக்கு"
> let textToHighlight = "க்"
> ```

As i googled and got few details from the link
[NSRange in Strings having dialects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281519/nsrange-in-strings-having-dialects).

But how to find() and advance() methods used in the given reference.
I am using xcode 11.2 and swift version 4

**EDIT:**

After a long time, i found a nearest solution to highlight / change foreground color of my matched character in the text as below,

```
func characterToHighlight(text: String, highlight: String) -> NSAttributedString? {

    guard let match = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: highlight, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
        return nil
    }

    let textStroke: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .strokeColor : UIColor.white,
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
    .strokeWidth : -2.0,
    ]

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        match
        .matches(in: text, options: .withTransparentBounds,
        range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
        .forEach {
        attributedString.addAttributes(textStroke, range: $0.range)
        }

    return attributedString
}

if let matchedCharacter = characterToHighlight(text: text, highlight: textToHighlight){titleLabel.attributedText = matchedCharacter}
```

This code works for the matched character of tamil letters in the string but the foreground of the other letters were black.
I need the non-matched characters in blue color and the matched characters in red color.

How to achieve this?

**ANSWER:**

```
let titleLabel: UILabel!
let myText = "கொக்கு"
let textToHighlight = "க்"
titleLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
let textStroke: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .strokeColor : UIColor.white,
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.blue,
    .strokeWidth : -2.0,
    ]
let highlightTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
.strokeColor : UIColor.white,
.foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
.strokeWidth : -4.0,
]
let textTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myText)
textTitle.addAttributes(textStroke, range: textHighlightRange)
if let matchedCharacterRange = getRange(text: text, highlight: textToHighlight)
{
    textTitle.addAttributes(highlightTextAttributes, range: matchedCharacterRange)
}
titleLabel.attributedText = textTitle


func getRange(text: String, highlight: String) -> NSRange? {

    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: highlight, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
        return nil
    }

    var highlightRange: NSRange?

    regex
    .matches(in: text, options: .withTransparentBounds,
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
    .forEach {
        highlightRange = $0.range
    }
    return highlightRange
}
```

I am unable to post my answer separately, so i am editing my question and posting the answer in the same.

Experts, please review and correct me if am wrong.

Thanks for your support.